# Simple LED circuit keeps breaking

Tags: led, breadboard

I've been trying to get into electronics after finding an old electronics kit in the back of my closet. It came with an Arduino Uno, a bread board, a bunch of wires, LEDs, resistors, and other things.

I decided to try to see if I could light an LED on a bread board for a few minutes before trying the Arduino.

I built this circuit:
[image]

When I try the circuit the LED lights but 30 seconds later it gets hot and burns out.

I'd rather know what I'm doing wrong before I burn more of my LEDs.

Comment: 10 bucks says you mis-wired it on the breadboard. Or have the wrong resistor. If you wired it up as your schematic shows, then it would never heat up, and probably be a pin prick of a light. 10kΩ resistor means it would get a fraction of a milliamp. A 10Ω resistor though, your talking around 90 milliamps, 4.5 times more than you should be pushing through a normal led.

Comment: Please post a photograph of the whole circuit. I mean the actual circuit. Because I am sure something is not the way you think it is.

Comment: 3V battery and 2.1V RED can handle 20mA with current limiting 3-2.1V = 0.9V drop/20mA  =  ~50 ohms  but 70k  would be off  , while 100 ohms gives ~10mA ... 220 ohms ~5 mA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how a breadboard is connected internally. Check your connections, you may have bypassed the resistors.

[image]

Comment: It looks like I screwed up the wiring. After mimicking your diagram It appears to work flawlessly. Thanks!